# How can I output 5V from ESP8266 NodeMCU 3.3v input?

Tags: arduino, voltage, amplifier

I want to control a High Torque Servo using the esp8266 with PWM. This servo's operation voltage is in the range: 4.8V - 7.2V. With the esp8266, the GPIO pins can only output a maximum 3.3v. What's the most simple way to achieve the 5v output from esp8266?

Comment: You likely do not need to do anything except connect it.  Hobby Servos are for the most part known to work well with 3.3v input.

Comment: Why is this tagged "arduino"?  It doesn't seem like any original or clone Arduino part is in use here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - while I'm sure the 3.3v output of the ESP8266 will be adequate for a small servo, I suspect the 12mA max current will be a bit more of a limitation.

Comment: @Jules - you seem to be seriously confusing something.  The question is about *controlling* the servo, not about *powering* it.  A servo does not draw its power from the signal line.  The signal line conveys only information via quite low currents, power is delivered via the power line.  They typically share a ground.

Answer (score 1):

Use a suitable NPN BJT to switch the 5V to the servo.

Comment: This is unnecessary.  Further, if you were going to do it this way, you wound need to take the inversion into account in the software/timer pulse generation.  And as the NPN would only drive low and not the high side that is the actual subject of the question, you'd also need a pull-up resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a level shifter, they are easy to use and are cheaply available.
These small chips are very handy and are bi directional, you share it both power supplies, for any 3.3v LV1-4 get corresponding 5v from hv1-4

Ex: [Link](https://www.electronicscomp.com/i2c-4-channel-3.3v-to-5v-bi-directional-logic-level-converter?gclid=Cj0KCQjwraqHBhDsARIsAKuGZeGTuPcA5uQ_S2nNd8jevcc4ZKd2rCS4qLdjTUrkJpsuPTvaYIoI8VcaAn1sEALw_wcB)